# Eclipse Plugin: If Annotation is not present, AbstractAnnotationHover results in a NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**What i have:** I develop an Eclipse editor and override the getTextHover Method in the SourceViewerConfiguration with this method:

```
public ITextHover getTextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {
                return new AbstractAnnotationHover(true) {
                    public Object getHoverInfo2(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
                        IAnnotationModel model = ((SourceViewer) textViewer).getAnnotationModel();
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Iterator<Annotation> parent = 
                        ((IAnnotationModelExtension2)model).getAnnotationIterator(hoverRegion.getOffset(), 
                                hoverRegion.getLength(), true, true);
                        Iterator<?> iter = new JavaAnnotationIterator(parent, false); 
                        Annotation annotation = null;
                        Position position = null;
                        while (iter.hasNext()) {
                            Annotation a = (Annotation) iter.next();
                            Position p = model.getPosition(a);
                            annotation = a;
                            position = p;
                        }
                        return new AnnotationInfo(annotation, position, textViewer) {
                            public ICompletionProposal[] getCompletionProposals() {
                                ICompletionProposal proposal1 = null;
                                IMarkerResolution [] resolutions = null;
                                ICompletionProposal [] com = null;
                                if (annotation instanceof MarkerAnnotation) {
                                    resolutions = new ErrorResolution().getResolutions(((MarkerAnnotation) annotation).getMarker());
                                    if(resolutions.length != 0){
                                        proposal1 = new MarkerResolutionProposal(resolutions[0], 
                                                ((MarkerAnnotation) annotation).getMarker());
                                        return new ICompletionProposal[] { proposal1 };
                                    }
                                }
                                return com ;
                            }
                        };
                    } 
                };  
  }
```

It displays QuickFixes when hovering over an annotated error in the code viewer. But if i hover over an error, which has no quick fix or just a correct line of code, it results in the following error:

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractAnnotationHover$AnnotationInformationControl.createAnnotationInformation(AbstractAnnotationHover.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractAnnotationHover$AnnotationInformationControl.deferredCreateContent(AbstractAnnotationHover.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractAnnotationHover$AnnotationInformationControl.setInput(AbstractAnnotationHover.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.internalShowInformationControl(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.presentInformation(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.presentInformation(AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.doPresentInformation(TextViewerHoverManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$5.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 24 more

and the message of the annotation is not shown.

**What I want:** I want, that if i hover iver an error where a quick fix is available, the quick fix is shown and if there is no one, just the annotation message is shown.

Comment: If this is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.AbstractAnnotationHover` you should not be using it in the first place [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). Write your own class implementing `ITextHoverExtension` and `ITextHoverExtension2`

Comment: But how to include the code of my getHoverInfo2 Method into the getHoverInfo2 method of my new class?